# Validation of checkbox form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

I am new to programming. The current problem that i am facing is the lack to display the correct answer of the checkbox question. The question number is 4, for example the selection of question 4 will not display the correct answer River Thames. Making sure the question number 4 is correct.

Javascript:

```
myTimer = setTimeout('alert("Time out")', 600000); /*alert will appear after 60 second*/

function processMyForm() {
var chosenans1 = document.mainForm.answer1.value;
var a1;

//alert(document.mainForm.answer1.value);
//alert(document.getElementById('answer2'));
var chosenans2 = document.getElementById('answer2').value;
var a2;



var chosenans4 = document.mainForm.answer4.checked;
var a4;




// ----------------------------

var total;

// --------------------------------

if (chosenans1 == "England") /*if radio value of answer1 is "England"*/ {
a1 = 2; /*correct answer for 2 marks*/
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 1 is correct.</span> "; /*print out correct at bottom of the page at <div id = "result1">*/
} else {
a1 = -1; /*incorrect answer for -1 mark*/
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 1 is 'England'.</span>"; /*print out incorrect at <div id = "result1">*/
}

// ---------------------

if (chosenans2 == "Stonehenge") {
a2 = 2;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 2 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a2 = -1;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 2 is 'Stonehenge'.</span>";
}

// -------------------

if (chosenans3 == "2012") {
a3 = 2;
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 3 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a3 = -1;
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 3 is '2012'.</span>";
}

// ---------------------

if (chosenans4 == "River Thames") {
a4 = 2;
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 4 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a4 = -1;
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 4 is 'River Thames'.</span>";
}



// --------------------------------------------------------

total = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 ;//+ a5 + a6; /*add marks(2 or -1) together*/

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Your mark is " + total); //print out your total mark at <div id = "result">
alert("Your mark is " + total); //prompt total mark in small window

if (total < 4) {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "none"; //remove background image
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#bb0000"; //add a background colour
} else {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "none";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#006600";
}

clearTimeout(myTimer); //stop timer
}


function getValue(qArray) { //get value from radio array
var i;
for (i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
if (qArray[i].checked) return qArray[i].value;
}
return "";
}
```

HTML:

```
     <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">


        <p>1: London belongs to:</p><br>



        <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England">England<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland<br/>
        <!--radio buttons with different values-->


        <br>
        <p>2: Which of the following is not in London:</p><br>


        <select id="answer2">
        <option value="">Select an answer</option>
        <option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
        <option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
        <option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>



        <br>
        <p>4: Which river runs through London:</p>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="La Seine">La Seine<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="Rhine River">Rhine River<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="River Thames">River Thames<br>









        <br>


        <input type="button" onclick="processMyForm()" value="Check answers">
        <!--a button called "Check answers" will run processMyForm procedure when user click-->

        </form>




<!--print out user's total mark-->
<br/>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: By validation are you wanting to make sure they have answered or make sure the answer is correct? by including your answers on the same page knowledgeable users would be able to view the answers - your validation should be server-side.

Comment: Making sure the question number 4 is correct.

Comment: None validation

Comment: if you want to allow multiple answers for a checkbox input you should change the name to include array notation for example `name="answer4[]"`

Comment: Could you apply this change for me please

Comment: Your markup is also missing the opening `<form>` tag. you have nothing with an id of answer1. You may need to provide a [mcve]  to get any further with this question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you left off the opening `<form name="mainForm">`,
it looks like you need to add the "result" elements.

The result innerHTML assignment, eg:`document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = ...`, is throwing an error because there is no element with `id="result4"`.

Add something like this where you want to see the correct results messages displayed:

```
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>
<div id="result5"></div>
<div id="result6"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
myTimer = setTimeout('alert("Time out")', 600000); /*alert will appear after 60 second*/

function processMyForm() {
var chosenans1 = document.mainForm.answer1.value;
var a1;

//alert(document.mainForm.answer1.value);
//alert(document.getElementById('answer2'));
var chosenans2 = document.getElementById('answer2').value;
var a2;

var chosenans3 = document.mainForm.answer3.value;
var a3;
//alert(document.mainForm.answer3.value);

var chosenans4 = document.mainForm.answer4.checked;
var a4;


var chosenans5 = document.mainForm.answer5.value;
var a5;

var chosenans6 = document.mainForm.answer6.value;
var a6;



// ----------------------------

var total;

// --------------------------------

if (chosenans1 == "England") /*if radio value of answer1 is "England"*/ {
a1 = 2; /*correct answer for 2 marks*/
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 1 is correct.</span> "; /*print out correct at bottom of the page at <div id = "result1">*/
} else {
a1 = -1; /*incorrect answer for -1 mark*/
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 1 is 'England'.</span>"; /*print out incorrect at <div id = "result1">*/
}

// ---------------------

if (chosenans2 == "Stonehenge") {
a2 = 2;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 2 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a2 = -1;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 2 is 'Stonehenge'.</span>";
}

// -------------------

if (chosenans3 == "2012") {
a3 = 2;
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 3 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a3 = -1;
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 3 is '2012'.</span>";
}

// ---------------------

if (chosenans4 == "River Thames") {
a4 = 2;
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = "<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 4 is correct.</span>";
} else {
a4 = -1;
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = "<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 4 is 'River Thames'.</span>";
}

// -------------------------

if (chosenans5 == "Pound") {
a5 = 2;
document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = ("<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 5 is correct.</span>");
} else {
a5 = -1;
document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = ("<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 5 is 'Pound'.</span>");
}

if (chosenans6 == "David Cameron") {
a6 = 2;
document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = ("<span class='correct'>Your answer to question 6 is correct.</span>");
} else {
a6 = -1;
document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = ("<span class='incorrect'>The correct answer to question 6 is 'David Cameron'.</span>");
}

// --------------------------------------------------------

total = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 ;//+ a5 + a6; /*add marks(2 or -1) together*/

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ("Your mark is " + total); //print out your total mark at <div id = "result">
alert("Your mark is " + total); //prompt total mark in small window

if (total < 4) {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "none"; //remove background image
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#bb0000"; //add a background colour
} else {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "none";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#006600";
}

clearTimeout(myTimer); //stop timer
}


function getValue(qArray) { //get value from radio array
var i;
for (i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
if (qArray[i].checked) return qArray[i].value;
}
return "";
}
```

```html
<form name="mainForm">
 <p>1: London belongs to:</p><br>



<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England">England<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland<br/>
<!--radio buttons with different values-->


<br>
<p>2: Which of the following is not in London:</p><br>


<select id="answer2">
<option value="">Select an answer</option>
<option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
<option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
<option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<p>3: Which year's Olympic games was hosted by London:</p>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="2012">2012<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="2008">2008<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="2004">2004<br/>

<br>
<p>4: Which river runs through London:</p>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="La Seine">La Seine<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="Rhine River">Rhine River<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="answer4" value="River Thames">River Thames<br>








<br/><p>5: What is the name of the currency used in London:</p>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer5" value="Dollar">Dollar<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer5" value="Pound">Pound<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer5" value="Euro">Euro<br/>






<br/><p>6: Who is the current Prime Minister of the UK (2014):</p>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer6" value="Tony Blair">Tony Blair<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer6" value="Gordon Brown">Gordon Brown<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer6" value="David Cameron">David Cameron<br/>


<br>


<input type="button" onclick="processMyForm()" value="Check answers">
<!--a button called "Check answers" will run processMyForm procedure when user click-->

</form>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
<div id="result4"></div>
<div id="result5"></div>
<div id="result6"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I have these changes applied still not displaying the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind this solution is bad , but it will solve your problem without changing all your code structure

first: lets add an id to the River thames line.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="correct" name="answer4" value="River Thames">River Thames<br>
```

second: change the javascript to check if the id is checked instead of getting the value

```
var chosenans4 = document.getElementById('correct').checked;
```

third: the verification is now against an true or false so

```
if (chosenans4) {
//your code
```

this will keep you open to all the options being selected and you still say it is true, but that would be a different problem than the one you presented here! hope it helps :) btw here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxfh1jad/